# Name of orchestral styles of Krzysztof Penderecki and Elliot Goldenthal

Tags: orchestra, musescore, styles

I just came across [Krzysztof Penderecki's Threnody for the Victims of Hiroshima](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp3BlFZWJNA) after learning of his death this morning. The orchestral style is much like that heard in [Elliot Goldenthal's score for Alien 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDqhEa7HUl4); only the first piece I mentioned is a bit more abstract or "dryer". Goldenthal's score has some exceptionally intricate parts, especially Adagio. What is the name of this (or these, relatively) style and what are some good examples of those styles?

Comment: _Threnody for the Victims of Hiroshima_ is the most spine chilling piece of music I've ever heard. Look for "sonorism" and "aleatoric". There's lots of detail in the score as far as articulation goes, but the pitching element is in places left to the individual performers.

Comment: I've seen this type of question more often in Music Fans Stack Exchange.